# Consistent status bar appearance on Android

Tags: android, flutter

I have a freshly created Flutter app, and I configured my splash screen to display some background color and app icon in the middle.

By default, Android splash starts with status bar that looks dark semi-transparent. I wanted to change the color to be the same as splash background. I managed do this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/splash_color</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/splash_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

It  works, but only for the few first milliseconds. After that, the logo jumps up a little and status bar appears again. This happens before main method even starts.

How can I setup this so that status bar looks exactly the same from the start, until home page is shown?

EDIT:
I prepared source code: https://github.com/szotp/splash_status_problem
The jump up does not appear in completely now project for some reason, but this semi transparent background can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

@szotp, i had similar issue when i tried to implement splash screen so i used [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package instead. It auto-generates native code for splash screens, all you need to do is provide image and color. It will merge your status bar with same color as your screen background color. Not sure what yours look like but it worked really well for me.

Comment: This is the package that I used. I added example project with screenshots to better illustrate my problem.

Comment: Odd, seems to be working fine for me. Also, have you tested a release version (`flutter run --release`) of your app? Flutter's debug version is slow and buggy.